# NSURLRequest properly format multipart/form-data

Tags: objective-c, curl, nsurlrequest

I've created an NSURLRequest that's firing off requests OK. I've got it wired to requestbin, but instead of requestbin parsing the pertinent form data, it's seeing it as raw body.

I've got a working CURL command that does this correctly, and as far as I can tell both request raw bodies look the same -- I can't figure out what in the Obj-c I need to change to get those form parameters to work properly.

Here's the inspect link for the requestbin: http://requestb.in/1iszums1?inspect

**Working CURL:**

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer token" -H "X-ADN-Pretty-JSON: 1" -F "type=com.example.test" -F "content=@/Users/me/Desktop/test.jpg" "http://re
questb.in/1iszums1"
```

**Obj-c**

```
NSString* url = @"http://requestb.in/1iszums1";
UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0f);
NSString* token = @"token";
NSString* name = @"test.jpg";
NSString* type = @"com.example.test";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:60];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"------------------------------6c491b1c62c8";

// set Content-Type in HTTP header
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", token] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[request setValue:@"1" forHTTPHeaderField: @"X-ADN-Pretty-JSON"];

// post body
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];    

// add params (all params are strings)
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"type\"\r\n\r\n%@\r\n", type] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"content\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", name] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    // add image data
if (imageData) {

    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imageData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// set the content-length
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[body length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@ %@", response, responseBody);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not having tried it, my guess is that you are missing a couple of dashes on your boundary:
change

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

to

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Its tough to keep all of the dashes figured out. If your boundary string as declared in the content type is "foo" then you will need to separate each part with "--foo" and end the whole form data with "--foo--"